# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Tags: xcode4.2, ios-provisioning

I'm trying to install my app in my iphone, but It doesnt work.

I'm following the steps in "Launch assistant" here:

https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action

I think everything is ok, the certificate was installed before, I checked and it is in the "keyChan access"

I ckecked and the provisioning profile is asocciated to my iphone:

[image]

When I try to "run" to install in my iphone, I receive this error.

why is this happening?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please check the bundle identifier/APPID used for creating this provision profile and the bundle identifier of your app are same or not.